# Measure the shell script execution time in milliseconds on Mac OS

Tags: macos, shell, time, milliseconds

I was wondering if there is the way to get time in milliseconds from shell script on Mac OS.

I need it to time how much certain query runs.

Now I can only get the time in seconds:

```
Start=`date +%s`
End =`date +%s`
Time=$Start-$End
```

Answer (score 17):

You could use the benchmarking-tool `hyperfine` (https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine).

It is more elaborate than `time`, by default runs your command multiple times and gives you mean runtime, deviation, min, and max.

**Simple usage**

```
hyperfine your_command
```

Result looks like this ([result of hyperfine 'sleep 0.5'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z10n8.png)):

```
bash-3.2$ hyperfine 'sleep 0.5'
Benchmark #1: sleep 0.5
  Time (mean ± σ):     505.6 ms ±   1.5 ms    [User: 0.8 ms, System: 1.2 ms]
  Range (min … max):   503.1 ms … 508.8 ms    10 runs
```

There is one caveat, the minimum number of runs is 2 (`hyperfine -r 2 'your command'`).

**Installation**

Hyperfine can be installed via Homebrew:

```
brew install hyperfine
```

For more info see: https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine#on-macos

Answer (score 9):

just use the 'time' command:

```
time something
```

something could be a shell, or a command (find, etc)

the "real" time is the total elapsed time you want, and includes milliseconds

Comment: actually, sorry, time is not in milliseconds... it's lower than the second though

Answer (score 0):

Since Mac OS is BSD-like system, its `date` does not support the %N parameter you need.

You could though consider installing the [GNU Core Utils](http://rudix.org/packages/coreutils.html).

It will allow you to get the time in [the usual Linux way](https://serverfault.com/a/151112).

I suppose, the `time something` command will also output the result with milliseconds then.